# Qt Quick - What is the best way to animate an image transition while component state changes?

Tags: qt, animation, qml, state, qtquick2

With Qt Quick, I created a custom button which looks like that:

[image]

This button also contains several states (default, hover, pressed), and the transition between each states is animated. I found a way to animate each properties easily with the Qt Quick engine, except for the image one. Indeed, I want to animate the image transition, by performing a crossfade between states.

However I couldn't found a such animator for images. The only way I found was to add 3 images to my button, one for each states, and to animate their respective opacity.

Below is the code for my buttons:

```css
Button
{
    property bool hoveredBtn: false
    property bool pressedBtn: false

    id: btAnimStateDemo
    height: 40
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.rightMargin: 5
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.leftMargin: 5
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 290
    state: "DEFAULT"

    // the button background
    background: Rectangle
    {
        id: btAnimStateDemoBg
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    // the button text
    Text
    {
        id: btAnimStateDemoText
        text: qsTr("A button showing animated states (default, hovered, pressed)")
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        font.bold: true
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Image
    {
        id: btAnimStateDemoDefaultImage
        width: 30
        height: 30
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        opacity: 1.0
        source: "Resources/Palette.svg"
    }

    Image
    {
        id: btAnimStateDemoHoverImage
        width: 30
        height: 30
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        opacity: 0.0
        source: "Resources/Smile.svg"
    }

    Image
    {
        id: btAnimStateDemoPressedImage
        width: 30
        height: 30
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        opacity: 0.0
        source: "Resources/Woman.svg"
    }

    // the component state array
    states:
    [
        State
        {
            name: "DEFAULT"
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; color: "green"}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; radius: 4}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoDefaultImage; opacity: 1.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoHoverImage; opacity: 0.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoPressedImage; opacity: 0.0}
        },
        State
        {
            name: "HOVERED"
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; color: "red"}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; radius: 10}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoDefaultImage; opacity: 0.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoHoverImage; opacity: 1.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoPressedImage; opacity: 0.0}
        },
        State
        {
            name: "PRESSED"
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; color: "blue"}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoBg; radius: 15}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoDefaultImage; opacity: 0.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoHoverImage; opacity: 0.0}
            PropertyChanges { target: btAnimStateDemoPressedImage; opacity: 1.0}
        }
    ]

    // the matching transitions between states
    transitions:
    [
        Transition
        {
            from: "*"; to: "DEFAULT"
            ColorAnimation { property: "color"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
            NumberAnimation { properties: "radius, opacity"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
        },
        Transition
        {
            from: "*"; to: "HOVERED"
            ColorAnimation { property: "color"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
            NumberAnimation { properties: "radius, opacity"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
        },
        Transition
        {
            from: "*"; to: "PRESSED"
            ColorAnimation { property: "color"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
            NumberAnimation { properties: "radius, opacity"; easing.type: Easing.Linear; duration: 1000 }
        }
    ]

    // the mouse area which will apply the correct state in relation to the current mouse status
    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onEntered: {btAnimStateDemo.state = "HOVERED"; btAnimStateDemo.hoveredBtn = true;}
        onExited: {btAnimStateDemo.state = btAnimStateDemo.pressedBtn ? "PRESSED" : "DEFAULT"; btAnimStateDemo.hoveredBtn = false;}
        onPressed: {btAnimStateDemo.state = "PRESSED"; btAnimStateDemo.pressedBtn = true;}
        onReleased: {btAnimStateDemo.state = btAnimStateDemo.hoveredBtn ? "HOVERED" : "DEFAULT"; btAnimStateDemo.pressedBtn = false;}
    }
}
```

The above code works well, and reaches the purpose I planned, but is a little complicated from my point of view. It would be wonderful if an animator like `NumberAnimation` or `ColorAnimation` would exist for the images, but I found none.

So my question is: Is there a simpler way to animate an image transition between component states than my above proposed solution? Do Qt Quick propose an animator to reach a such purpose?

Comment: I don't think this exists, so maybe you should file a feature request with Qt? (maybe first wait for some answer ;-) )

Comment: So following your suggestion, I opened a thread on the Qt bug tracker: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81292

Answer (score 0):

Create a SpriteSheet that assigns states to each of the three frames then set the interpolate property to true to have it transition between the images.

Sprite Animations with SpriteSequence
SpriteSequence demonstrates using a sprite sequence to draw an animated and interactive bear. The SpriteSequence object defines five different sprites. The bear is initially in a still state:

```
      Sprite{
          name: "still"
          source: "content/BearSheet.png"
          frameCount: 1
          frameWidth: 256
          frameHeight: 256
          frameDuration: 100
          to: {"still":1, "blink":0.1, "floating":0}
      }
```

When the scene is clicked, an animation sets the sprite sequence to the falling states and animates the bear's y property.

```
  SequentialAnimation {
      id: anim
      ScriptAction { script: image.goalSprite = "falling"; }
      NumberAnimation { target: image; property: "y"; to: 480; duration: 12000; }
      ScriptAction { script: {image.goalSprite = ""; image.jumpTo("still");} }
      PropertyAction { target: image; property: "y"; value: 0 }
  }
```

At the end of the animation the bear is set back to its initial state.